# AWS API Gateway $input variable in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to log the [$input variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference) (body variables) of a request to API Gateway from CloudWatch?

The Log format of the Custom Access Logging doesn't seem to accept $input.body or any of the other $input functions:

```
{"requestId": "$context.requestId",  "ip": "$context.identity.sourceIp",  "caller": "$context.identity.caller",  "user": "$context.identity.user",  "requestTime": "$context.requestTime",  "httpMethod": "$context.httpMethod",  "resourcePath": "$context.resourcePath",  "status": "$context.status",  "protocol": "$context.protocol",  "responseLength": "$context.responseLength", "body": "$input.body", params: "$input.params()"}
```

Comment: I am also running into this same problem, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: it seems aws doesn't support $input variables for custom access logging. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=860814&tstart=0

Answer (score 4):

## Short answer: No

You can use `$context` variables in the access logging as documented in

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html.

Other variables including `$input` are not supported. If you want to log the request/response header values, you can use execution logging with enabling 'Log full requests/responses data'.